# Unable to import new Gradle project:failed to find Build Tools revision 25.2.4

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

When I try to import https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-firebase this project in eclipse,I got this error

"Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0."

I have done installation of latest android sdk tools 25.2.4 from android sdk manager and updated the following changes in build.gradle.

compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.2.4"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

currently I am getting this error

"failed to find Build Tools revision 25.2.4"

Can anyone tell me,how do I fix this?

Update

I am still getting this error while importing that project,how to fix this?

"Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0."
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
    file:/Users/divya/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    file:/Users/divya/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
    file:/Applications/android/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.pom
    file:/Applications/android/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar
Required by:
    de.tomgrill.gdxfirebase.android:android:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT > com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check buildToolsVersion, you have in Android SDK Manager. Currently latest is 25.0.2.

```
Android SDK Build-tools is different from 
Android SDK Tools(latest 25.2.4) and 
Android SDK Platform-tools(latest 25.0.3).
```

Hopefully it may be helpful

Thanks

Comment: update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+' in build.gradle of root project and gradle wrapper distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip @DivKala